# Carleman's condition for Catalan numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, catalan-numbers

I've been going through some elementary random matrix theory and in these [lecture notes](https://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/%7Ebordenave/IMPA-RMT.pdf) we say a probability measure is completely determined by its moments so long as it obey's Carleman's condition i.e. the sequence of moments $m_k$ are such that
$$
\sum_{k \geq 1} m_k^{-1/(2k)}= \infty.
$$ Later on when the semicircle distribution is brought up, whose moments are 0 for odd moments and the Catalan numbers for even numbers, they use a complex analytic method to prove that the moments are completely determined by the probability measure which is natural following Hadamard's formula. However I was wondering if a pure real analysis proof could still be constructed as I haven't found anything online, i.e. is the criterion
$$
\sum_{k \geq 1} C_k^{-1/(2k)}= \infty
$$
obeyed without analytic continuation? I've tried using Sterling's Formula which I hoped would cancel the exponent as well but no success as this series tends to zero.

Comment: Please collect in the question all needed ingrediends, instead of delegating to a 60 pages link. Introducing or at least directly referencing the Carleman's condition - if we really need it - would be nice. We have a complex analytic proof for what? (What does it mean "for the semicircle"?! This is less than an *a propos* for a long mathematical story.) And what is a "series proof"? Also show explicitly the own attempts, a potential answerer will have to type else a lot. (Possibly missing the point of the question.)

Comment: Okay I'll add the one line for what Carleman's condition is.

Comment: As for my own answer I just said simply using an algebraic approximation for $n!$ by Sterling's formula since I'd hoped the powers would cancel leaving a harmonic series but this wasn't the case.

Comment: This $-1/2k$ in the exponent, is it $-1/(2k)$ or $-k/2$?

Comment: Few readers will get to the end of the first paragraph not wondering about what could be the moments of a general probably measure on a measurable space $(X,\mathscr A)$.

Comment: @Ruy The core of the question I'm asking has nothing to do with probabilitu distributions buth rather as a question on the convergence of a series. I could rewrite the question asking whether or not the infinite sum of $C_k^{-1/2k}$ diverges to positive infinity or not.

Comment: @Vincent It's -$1/(2k)$, I'll make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asymptotically, $C_k \sim \frac{4^k}{k^{3/2}\sqrt{\pi}}$.  Therefore,
$$ \lim_{k \to \infty} C_k^{-\frac{1}{2k}} = \frac{1}{2} \lim_{k \to \infty} \pi^{\frac{1}{4 k}} k^{\frac{3}{4k}} = \frac{1}{2} \lim_{k \to \infty}  \pi^{\frac{1}{4 k}} \exp\left(\frac{3 \log k}{4 k}\right) = \frac{1}{2} \left( 1 \cdot \exp(0) \right) = \frac{1}{2} $$
Since the terms in the series do not in fact tend toward zero, the series diverges.

Comment: Thanks for this, didn't know about this asymptotic relation.

Comment: No worries.  The asymptotic relation is just what you get when you plug in Stirling's formula to the definition of $C_k$ and simplify.